# Запись структуры в файл

Tags: c#, файлы, структуры

Приветствую всех!

Как записать структуру в файл?
Пробовал через сериализацию:

```
    [Serializable]
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    struct Header
    {
       UInt32 DW_01; // 0x00000100
       UInt32 DW_02; // 0x00000400
       UInt32 DW_03; // 0x00000000
       UInt32 ImgFSize;
       UInt32 OrigFSize;
       UInt32 FOffset;
       UInt32 DW_04; // 0x00000000
    }

    public void UN()
    {
        byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("C:\\1.img");
        Header header;(Header)Marshal.PtrToStructure(Marshal.UnsafeAddrOfPinnedArrayElement(bytes, 0), typeof(Header));
        FileStream f = new FileStream("C:\\1.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);         
       BinaryFormatter ser = new BinaryFormatter();
       ser.Serialize(f, header);
    }
```

Но на выходе получаю такую ерунду:

```
    яяяя          ?SCModule, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null   SCModule.SC9800+Header   DW_01   HHHHHH
```

Можно ли как-нибудь записать структуру в файл или сериализовать без этого мусора?

Comment: Чего вы хотите добиться **в итоге?** При правильном подходе к сериализации формат, используемый `BinaryFormatter'ом` вас совершенно не должен волновать.

Comment: Хочу считать заголовок файла в структуру, а затем из структуры записать в другой файл.

Comment: @Sharp

- Я посмотрел, что вы работаете с какой-то там прошивкой - здесь сериализация неприменима в принципе и, вообще говоря, механизм сериализации решает совершенно другие задачи.

- Явно добавьте в ваш класс методы `LoadFromBytes` и `DumpToBytes` и работайте либо на уровне `byte[]`, либо на уровне [`Stream.ReadByte`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.io.stream.readbyte).

Comment: Да верно, работаю с прошивкой. Первый раз работаю с такими вещами. Шифровщик\Дешифровщик уже написал, вот теперь пытаюсь сделать анпакер. Спасибо за совет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это не мусор, сериализатор пишет в файл информацию о типе, в который ему надо будет десериализовывать объект. Для того чтобы контролировать формат файла, используйте [`BinaryWriter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.binarywriter.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Ну что тут сложного? Создать массив байтов, скопировать туда нужный блок. Но вот насчет записи в файл тут есть хороший вариант

```
//Запись структуры
Header header = new Header();
byte[] array = new byte[Marshal.SizeOf(header)];
Marshal.StructureToPtr(header, Marshal.UnsafeAddrOfPinnedArrayElement(array, 0), false);
```

А потом записываем этот массив (своеобразный маленький буфер) в нужный файл с нужного места примерно вот так:

```
using (var stream = new System.IO.FileStream("C:/file.bin", System.IO.FileMode.Open,System.IO.FileAccess.Write))
            {
                //Перемещаемся в файле на 100 байт от начала
                stream.Seek(100, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);
                //Записываем буфер
                stream.Write(array, 0, array.Length);
            }
```

Тот же принцип открытия потока может пригодится и в вашем первом случае при чтении заголовка (не нужно грузить весь файл в массив)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но я уже разобрался)